# ¿De qué forma hacer énfasis en la mejor opción de un conjunto de malas opciones?

Tags: adverbios

Muchas veces escucho una forma de expresión como

> Votaré por el político X porque parece la menos peor de las opciones.

A la vista del diccionario panhispánico de dudas, hay un error en la comparación *menos peor*, puesto que la [versión 2005](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Cbumyr3WLD6Afn24Wr) del mismo reza lo siguiente:

> Tampoco es correcto el empleo [...] delante de adjetivos que ya son comparativos de por sí, como peor, mejor ...

La entrada en cuestión hace referencia al adverbio *más*, pero se puede entender del extracto que la misma conclusión es extrapolable a *menos*

No obstante y cometiendo el error a propósito, la intención del hablante en este caso es comunicar que ha elegido la mejor opción pero también quiere hacer explícito que lo hace dentro de un conjunto de malas opciones.

Mi pregunta es, ¿De qué manera se puede comunicar la misma idea sin hacer un uso incorrecto del lenguaje?

Comment: ¿Posiblemente "menos mal"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La forma correcta de expresar esa idea consiste en decir: "menos malo".

- Votaré por el político X porque parece la menos mala de las opciones. (Todas son malas, pero ésa lo es en menor grado.)

También hablamos de "mal menor" cuando nos vemos obligados a optar entre varias alternativas negativas:

- Votaré por el político X porque parece el mal menor.

Comment: Me gusta la expresión del mal menor, la había oído y no sé por qué no se me ocurrió.

Answer (score -1):

Sí, es verdad que con las reglas del español, no se puede decir "menos peor". La forma correcta para decir la frase es "Votaré por el político X porque parece como la mejor opción de todos los candidatos." La frase "menos peor" es incorrecta gramaticalmente, pero una forma similar para decir la frase es "la mejor". Así que la forma correcta para decir la oración es: "el político es la mejor opción de todos los candidatos."

Comment: Sí, pero de esta forma se pierde el matiz de "la mejor entre un conjunto de malas opciones"